# Having problems install py2app 0.5.2

Tags: python

I am a beginner at python so please excuse me for silly comments or rookie mistakes that i make. I was trying to install py2app 0.5.2 and i hit an error:

$Best match: altgraph 0.7.1
$Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/a/altgraph/altgraph-$0.7.1.tar.gz#md5=f65988bf153410a8514bcdad6a3a8ba6
$Processing altgraph-0.7.1.tar.gz
$Running altgraph-0.7.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-GGBuKJ/altgraph-$\0.7.1/egg-dist-tmp-NdWVjC
$error: doc/changelog.rst: No such file or directory

I was wondering what the solution to this problem is?

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
sudo port install py27-altgraph
```

That worked for me